# Unable to use ANT Design NG-ZORRO; export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I try to use the ANT Design NG-ZORRO library in my project. But when I compile the code I get the following warning:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/fesm5/ng-zorro-antd-core.js 2294:66-84
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
```

This results in a runtime error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at ng-zorro-antd-core.js:2294
    at Module../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/fesm5/ng-zorro-antd-core.js (ng-zorro-antd-core.js:2296)
```

I searched the internet and tried various version combinations of the packages involved. But was unable to get it to work.

Excerpt of the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.13",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.22",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "2.6.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "messagepack": "^1.1.10",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^8.3.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "rtcp-web-viewer": "^2.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  }
```

What do I need to do to resolve those warnings and errors to make the package work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using incompatible versions of the `ng-zorro-antd` library with the Angular libraries that you're using.

Versions `8.0.0` and up of the `ng-zorro-antd` library require you to update your Angular dependencies to use version `8.0.0` and above (see the [release notes for version `8.0.0`](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/releases/tag/8.0.0) for more info).

As such, you have to either:

- Update your Angular dependencies to version 8 and up (See the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io) for details on what to do to update), or
- Downgrade the `ng-zorro-antd` library to an older version (in this case, you should use the latest `7.x.x` version - `7.5.1`)

Comment: Thank you for your response; I've installed version 7.5.1 and resolved all the npm warnings. Now it seems to work :-).